# ngCordova getUUID() returns device is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

### ngCordova getUUID() returns device is undefined

I am using Ionic framework to build a mobile app , i need to retrieve the device UUID
i used ngCordova using the minified version from here
[ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/)!

here is my main module

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
.controller('test',function($scope,$cordovaDevice){
$scope.uuid=$cordovaDevice.getUUID();
console.log($cordovaDevice)
})
```

$cordovaDevice is defined as object when using console.log but when using $cordovaDevice.getUUID() it gives me 'device is not defined'  any help with that

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the cordovaDevice plugin using the command?

> `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`

Comment: Now it is `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until device is ready...

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
    $scope.UUID = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by calling $scope.$apply() after the call to $cordovaDevice.getUUID()

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
      $scope.account.imei =  $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
      $scope.$apply();

    }else {//For ionic serve
        $scope.account.imei = '12345';
        console.log($scope.account.imei);
    }
});
```

From the official documentation http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/, the cordova plugin returns a promise.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $cordovaPlugin.someFunction().then(success, error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've stated `ngCordova` correctly as a module dependency. I think all you need to do is inject `$cordovaDevice` into your controller with the full array syntax

```
  .controller('test',['$scope', '$cordovaDevice', function($scope, $cordovaDevice){
    $scope.uuid=$cordovaDevice.getUUID();
  }])
```

If that doesn't work have you checked that the the plugin is loading first?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work , but please, howa i can check that the plugin is loading first

Comment: Are you testing on a device or in a desktop browser? Also have you been through "Common Issues" on the ngCordova docs? http://ngcordova.com/docs/

Comment: i testing on my android device , yes i readed the common issues but it still not working

Comment: Only things I can suggest are 1) make sure your `ng-cordova.js` script is being loaded after `cordova.js` 2) make sure you're injecting `$cordovaDevice` as I said above 3) do all the things on the site like ensuring Cordova is latest version,  refreshing `android.json` and so on.  I've tried doing the above on device using the Ionic CLI, it builds fine and alerts the UUID to the user. Running Cordova commands in  a desktop browser will obviously show the 'device is undefined' error, but seems to work for me on device...

Comment: If still not working, try the Ionic forums, they are a bit more active than Stack Overflow for Ionic issues.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because you are asking for a device's details, whilst you are developing on your machine.

Look at the functions. None of them will return a suitable value on your dev env. Also Cordova is built for mobile devices - they haven't created a set of handlers for local dev.

- Returns the whole device object.
  getDevice()
- Returns the Cordova version.
  getCordova()
- Returns the name of the device's model or product.
  getModel()
- Returns the device's operating system name.
  getPlatform()
- Returns the device's Universally Unique Identifier.
  getUUID()
- Returns the operating system version.
  getVersion()